# How to share files between cPanel accounts?

Tags: linux, file-sharing, magento

I am setting up a multi-site/multi-store Magento installation, and I want each site to have its own cPanel account so I can setup the SSL and dedicated IP properly. I have tried to create a linux group called 'magento' and changed the files I need to share to that group (even added the users to that group), however when I try to access files through my scripts on those accounts it doesn't acknowledge the files exist. I first made a soft symbolic link which didn't work and then including them to their real location but it didn't work. Am I missing a step in allowing which users can access which files? I added the users to the magento group and like I said changed the group of the files I need to share to them but it's still not working.

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: Admin panels are [off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (see [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258) for some reasons). The community has decided that we want to close both old and new questions when such an admin panel is relevant ([link 1](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8086), [link 2](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/)).

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to share files is to not use cPanel with this.